# ORSSerialPort.send in SwiftUI won't connect

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, arduino, orsserialport

I want to send a byte to an Arduino with ORSserial from a Mac. The framework, hardware and Arduino code work when I use ORSSerialPort terminal demo code. It connects and sends a byte lighting up the Arduino tx/rx and output leds perfectly. However, when I use ORSSerial and SwiftUI to do the same it doesn't light up any leds at all. I've tried putting the class instantiation in different locations and putting the setup/open code in functions other than the init and even used button callbacks. Still not working in SwiftUI so far. I'm new to swift and swiftui so there may be horrible errors in my code but here it is. All suggestions/criticisms are welcome, thanks.

```
    import SwiftUI 
    import ORSSerial

    class myPort: NSObject, ORSSerialPortDelegate {

       var serialPort = ORSSerialPort(path: "/dev/cu.usbmodem14101")
       let myData = "2".data(using: .utf8)

       override init(){
           super.init()
           print("starting:")
           if (serialPort != nil){
               serialPort?.baudRate = 9600
               serialPort?.numberOfDataBits = 8
               serialPort?.numberOfStopBits = 1
               serialPort?.parity = .none
               serialPort?.usesRTSCTSFlowControl = false
               serialPort?.open()
               if ((serialPort?.isOpen) != nil){
                   serialPort?.send(myData!) // someData is an NSData object
                   print("sending: \(String(describing: myData))")
               } else {print("Error: opening port")}
           } else {print("Error: getting port")}
       }

       func serialPortWasRemovedFromSystem(_ serialPort: ORSSerialPort) {
           print("Error: port removed")
       }

       deinit {
           serialPort?.close()
           print("Port closed")
       }
    }
    
    struct ContentView: View { 
       var sendArduino = myPort()
       var body: some View {
           VStack{
              Text("Done yet?")
           }
           .frame(width: 400, height: 400)
       }
    }
```

Comment: Are you saying that your `myPort` code all works in another test circumstance, but not when used within the SwiftUI `View`?

Comment: Nope. The ORSserialPort example demo is a interface builder and swift terminal Xcode project that connects and sends a byte fine to my Arduino. When I tried to do the same with ORSserialPort and SwiftUI as above it doesn't even connect much less send the byte :/

Comment: Okay, now I'm more confused. By "nope", do you mean that yes, my assessment was correct?

Comment: maybe it is to do with entitlements/security. Have you setup:
 `<key>com.apple.security.device.serial</key>
 <true/>`
 
in your entitlements?
 
Have a look at the SwiftUI demo at:
https://github.com/janhendry/ORSSerialPort/tree/master/Examples/ORSSerialSwiftUIDemo/Swift/SwiftUIDemo/SwiftUIDemo

Comment: Sorry, my 'nope' was to say that any SwiftUI code I've tried to write didn't work. The ORSserial port demo is a simple terminal so I compiled that typed in the number 2 which sent to the Arduino fine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to workingdog's tip I just needed to add com.apple.security.device.serial to the entitlements as a boolean and set it to true :)